# FusionCharts with tooltip

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I am using FusionCharts to implement linechart with anchors and would like to see a tooltip on mouse over.
Standart tooltip is floating and not anchored. Is there such possibility?
Tooltip text is stored in dataset. How can I style it?
[image]

Comment: I think this customization is not readily supported in the core library, but you can drop a mail to support@fusioncharts.com, they could assist you with a custom solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by using bootstrap popup, jQuery and FusionCharts events:

```
 "events": {
               "drawComplete": function (eventObj) {
                    let lineDataset = eventObj.sender.args.dataSource.dataset.filter(function (dataset){return dataset.renderAs === 'line' && dataset.data.length > 0})[0];

                    let dataPlots = lineDataset.data.filter(function (obj) { return obj.anchorRadius != "0" });
                    var targetImages = $('g[class$="-line"] g[class$="-plot-group"]:last-child').prev().find("image:visible");//Linechart visible Anchors

                    //Built-in FusionCharts tooltip cannot be styled properly and anchored so we have to use bootstrap popover
                    targetImages.each(
                        function (index, image) {
                        $(image).popover({
                                content: dataPlots[index].tooltext,
                                placement: 'right',
                                trigger: 'hover'
                                })
                            }
                   );
                }
            }
```